# Can't get Profile object that belongs to User in django

Tags: django

I have a blog app in Django and on the home page I display all posts as well as the user that posted. However, I'm now trying to add the user's profile image next to the usernames and I can't seem to pull any data from the Profile object. In my templates, when I loop through the posts, code such as `{{ post.user }}` works fine, but when I try to extend beyond that like `post.user.profile.profile_image.url` nothing shows up.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='image.png', upload_to='profile_images', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(comments_count=Count('comments')).order_by('-created_date')
    common_tags = Post.tags.most_common()[:4]
    title = ""
    return render(request, 'post/home.html', {'posts': posts, 'common_tags': common_tags})
```

And in my html template I'm just doing a `{% for post in posts %}` loop.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Because you use a `ForeignKey`, a user can have *multiple* profiles.

Comment: You probably should change it to a `OneToOneField`.

Comment: That was it, thanks! So a Foreign Key is a One to Many relationship? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: no a many-to-one :)

Comment: ooooh ok, thank you! I'll accept your answer after the 8 minute timer is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` is a *many-to-one* relation, since multiple `Profile`s can all point to the *same* `User`. This also means that, if you do not specify a [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) you access the related profiles with `user.profile_set.all()`.

What you probably need is a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField). This is essentially a `ForeignKey`, but with a [**`unique=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) parameter, but the name convention is also different if you do not specify a `related_name=…`, then it is just `.modelname`, so that means that you access the `Profile` with `user.profile`.

You thus change this with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete= models.CASCADE
    )
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        default='image.png',
        upload_to='profile_images',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the answer as well as the thorough explanation!!